# Can't select from dropdown menu using selenium. Getting error cause <div> class not selectable

Tags: python

I am trying to automate adidas checkout but I can't seem to select state cause it's under a  class. I tried using selenium using xpath but all I am getting is errors. Does anyone know a workaround?

https://www.adidas.com/on/demandware.store/Sites-adidas-US-Site/en_US/COShipping-Show

```
<div class="materialize-element-field dwfrm_shipping_shiptoaddress_shippingAddress_countyProvince_d0hqvqbeydyh ng-binding"></div>

    dropdown = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'materialize-select-list dwfrm_shipping_shiptoaddress_shippingAddress_countyProvince')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Lester H\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 978, in find_element
    'value': value})['value']
  File "C:\Users\Lester H\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\Lester H\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: Compound class names not permitted
  (Session info: chrome=71.0.3578.98)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.44.609538 (b655c5a60b0b544917107a59d4153d4bf78e1b90),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17134 x86_64)

driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'dwfrm_shipping_shiptoaddress_shippingAddress_countyProvince')
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="a3c8c8aff59c7aa03489394641cfe4eb", element="0.587285728768483-1")>
dropdown = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'dwfrm_shipping_shiptoaddress_shippingAddress_countyProvince')
dropdown.click()
dropdown.click()
```

Comment: Code and full error stack please

Comment: Just added the error.